# Xcode, Cannot read bundle contents (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am at my wits end. I've been messing around trying to change the name of my iphone-app and have apparently broken something.
When I try to build I get the error message

> /Users/john/Desktop/ubernerds/fardig/renrakat.xcdatamodeld: Cannot
>   read bundle contents (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The
>   folder “renrakat.xcdatamodeld” doesn’t exist."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/john/Desktop/ubernerds/fardig/renrakat.xcdatamodeld,
>   NSUserStringVariant

There is a file called `renrakat.xcdatamodeld` in the folder `fardigt`, so what could be the problem? 
When I start my backup copy (made before I started making dumb changes) I get the same error when I try to build

Please help!

I'm running xcode 7.1.1

Comment: Make sure the file exists, run this on your terminal: `[ -e /Users/john/Desktop/ubernerds/fardig/renrakat.xcdatamodeld/ ] && echo "File exists" || echo "File do not exitsts"` and see if it returns `File exists`

Comment: You, sir have saved me a days work. I am endebted to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran the /Users/john/Desktop/ubernerds/fardig/renrakat.xcdatamodeld/ ] && echo "File exists" || echo "File do not exitsts" in the terminal I ofund that the file was indeed in the wrong folder. Moved it and everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following "work-around" could help !?

- 1. Start a brandneu project
- 2. Name it the way you want
- 3. Copy all resources from the damaged project to the new project
- 4. Try building again

Comment: This is the correct answer, if for no other reason, to teach me not to tinker with things I don't understand :) However, alaphao saved me the work (see comment on original question) Thank you guys! You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you can not find the lost file:

You create a new xcdatamodeld (right click on the old xcdatamodeld that error -> new file)

Xcode will create model.xcdatamodel

copy and paste old name to the new xcdatamodel (also delete old.xcdatamodeld first) and run project

the xcdatamodel folder in your project folder will replace with "old name 2 xcdatamodel folder"